# Woocommerce custom availability text shown multiple times when selecting variations

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm experiencing the following bug on a clients WooCommerce website. We use this free [Variations Swatch for Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce/) plugin. I have a variable product with **4 different colors**.

If all colors are sold out, when selecting a variation the "out of stock" custom message is shown. 
But when selecting a different variation the message is shown again, so there are now 2 blocks with "out of stock" custom message:

[image: Screenshot of the described issue]

I have a different product in this store with color and engine variations and there's no issue like this.

**Question:**
How can I make the out of stock custom message to be shown only once at the same time?

Here is the website [**live link**](http://www.minimoto.me/product/ekolibri/) to the product page, where the issue can be seen.

This is my code in the `functions.php` file of my theme:

```
// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );

function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
global $product;

// Variable product only
if($product->is_type('variable')):

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Ab: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                if($('p.availability')) $('p.availability').remove();
                $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
            } else {
                $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                console.log('NULL');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

endif;
}


// This filter for custom in stock and out of stock messages:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {


    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Dein Minimoto Produkt ist verfügbar!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Aktuell nicht vorrätig, bitte kontaktieren Sie uns telefonisch unter +49 403 486 2392', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: where's the question, you lost the question?

Comment: Sorry, question, how can I get the "out of stock" message to only display once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I have changed in your code:

```
'<p class="availability">+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+</p>'
```

To:

```
'<div class="availability">+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+</div>'
```

Avoiding repetitive malformed html `<p>` and `</p>` tags…

And changed:

```
if($('p.availability')) $('p.availability').remove();
```

To this better one:

```
if($('div.availability').html() != undefined ) $('div.availability').remove();
```

I have simplified the code in your wcs_custom_get_availability() function too…

So the correct code should be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() )
        $availability['availability'] = __('Dein Minimoto Produkt ist verfügbar!', 'woocommerce');
    else
        $availability['availability'] = __('Aktuell nicht vorrätig, bitte kontaktieren Sie uns telefonisch unter +49 403 486 2392', 'woocommerce');

    return $availability;
}

// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
    global $product;

    // Variable product only
    if($product->is_type('variable')):

        // Main Price
        $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
        $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Ab: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

        // Sale Price
        $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
        sort( $prices );
        $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

        if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
            $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
        }

        ?>
        <style>
            div.woocommerce-variation-price,
            div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
            div.hidden-variable-price {
                height: 0px !important;
                overflow:hidden;
                position:relative;
                line-height: 0px !important;
                font-size: 0% !important;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('select').blur( function(){
                var availability = '<div class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</div>';
                if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                    if($('div.availability').html() != undefined ) $('div.availability').remove(); // Just in case
                    $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append(availability);
                    console.log('IF - '+$('input.variation_id').val());
                } else {
                    $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                    if($('div.availability').html() != undefined ) $('div.availability').remove();
                    console.log('ELSE');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php

        echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
        <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and work … This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This row tells you everything

```
 $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
```

you are using append not html()

change your code to:

```
$('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()+'<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but where would I add this line?

Comment: @NiklasBuschner you need to alter this line, not add it

Comment: see second snippet